# NameError: global name 'Twitter' is not defined

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I installed the twitter wrapper for python installed it and running it but getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhartha/workspace/trouveunappart/src/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    sid()
  File "/home/siddhartha/workspace/trouveunappart/src/test.py", line 12, in sid
    t = Twitter(
NameError: global name 'Twitter' is not defined
```

the code is:

```
from twitter import *



CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_SECRET = ''


t = Twitter(
                auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
                CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
            )




since_ID = -1
max_ID = 0

while(since_ID != max_ID):
    search = t.search.tweets(q = k, count = 100, since_id = max_ID)

    print len(search['statuses'])
    if len(search['statuses']) == 0:
        print 'end'
        break


    since_ID = search['search_metadata']['since_id_str']
    max_ID = search['search_metadata']['max_id_str']
```

Comment: _Which one_ twitter library are we talking about?

Comment: @kirelagin http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/#development

Comment: does this deserve a -1 ? i think its hard to figure out why this doesn't work

Comment: @codious hmm, looks weird. Could you try to replace `from twitter import *` with `import twitter` and `t = Twitter(…)` with `t = twitter.Twitter(…)` and post new stack trace?

Comment: Also the code you've posted does not match your stack trace as I can't see `sid` function in your code.

Comment: its the code within the method sid() which i call

Comment: Does `api = twitter.Api()` fail?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siddhartha/workspace/trouveunappart/src/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    sid()
  File "/home/siddhartha/workspace/trouveunappart/src/test.py", line 12, in sid
    t = twitter.Twitter(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Twitter'

Comment: What's inside the `twitter` module/package? Sounds like there's nothing named `Twitter` inside.

Comment: api = twitter.Api() works

Comment: See my answer then. You've got another twitter library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess. Is it possible that you've got another twitter library installed? I mean, `import twitter` works for you, but there is not `twitter.Twitter` which should be there, if you are really using *python twitter tools*.

For example, [*python-twitter*](https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) doesn't have `twitter.Twitter`, but has `twitter.Api` which does not exist in *python twitter tools*. It seems that you've got *python-twitter*, not *python twitter tools*.